# Bitnami postgresql change max_connections

Tags: postgresql, terraform, bitnami, helm3, terraform-provider-helm

I am installing postgresql using terraform on my kubernetes cluster.

I am using bitnami https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql/11.6.19 this chart.

My terraform resource is something like below

```
resource "helm_release" "postgres" {
  chart = "postgresql"
  name = "postgresql-postgresql"
  version = "11.6.19"
  timeout = 600
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  namespace = "default"

  values = [
    file("${path.module}/postgresql-persistence/values.yaml")
  ]
}
```

And I am overriding few settings using **values.yaml** file, as below.

```
primary:
    extendedConfiguration: |
        max_connections = 400
    initdb:
        scripts:
            my_init_script.sql: |
                CREATE DATABASE iam;
                GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO sales;
```

But when I run this, I am getting following error in console.

```
rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: existing resource conflict: namespace: default, name: postgresql-postgresql-extended-configuration, existing_kind: /v1, Kind=ConfigMap, new_kind: /v1, Kind=ConfigMap
```

Can someone please tell me how can I set max_connection using terraform with bitnami chart ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a ConfigMap with the same name already present in the cluster?

Comment: No, I have not set anything other than above given code.

Comment: This happened on the first run for this resource?

Comment: Yes, and it's happening whenever I try to install.

Comment: Wait, that's a YML file right? Shouldn't it be then `max_connections: 400`?

Comment: Let me try this too.

Comment: @MarkoE, I tried this but getting same error.

Comment: I think you need to have a ConfigMap for that already defined, at least based on the comments from the default values file: `## @param primary.existingExtendedConfigmap Name of an existing ConfigMap with PostgreSQL Primary extended configuration
  ## NOTE: primary.extendedConfiguration will be ignored`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following

You already have **postgresql-postgresql-extended-configuration** configMap created.

by adding the following to your values.YAML

```
extendedConfiguration: |
        max_connections = 400
```

It will try to create a new configMap with the same **postgresql-postgresql-extended-configuration**

you can list all the config maps and delete **postgresql-postgresql-extended-configuration**

```
kubectl get configmap -n kubernetes-namespace

kubectl delete configmap config-map-name -n kubernetes-namespace
```

in your case config map name is postgresql-postgresql-extended-configuration

try to reinstall this worked for me