# GitLab Bitnami PostgreSQL not overriding shared_buffers

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, gitlab, bitnami

Following this topic: [Bitnami postgresql change max_connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218618/bitnami-postgresql-change-max-connections)

With the update to `16.x` version for self-hosted GitLab we needed to increase our max_connections from `100` to `200`.

After doing that, we noticed that our `shared_buffers` were set to `4MB` which is too low and according to docs a reasonable starting value for shared_buffers is 1/4 of the memory in your system. If you have less RAM you'll have to account more carefully for how much RAM the OS is taking up; closer to 15% is more typical there.

I have added the following in our `values.yaml`:

```bash
postgresql:
  install: true
  primary:
    extendedConfiguration: |
      max_connections = 200
      shared_buffers = 512MB
```

Tested this on one of our test environments and we saw that it allocated 512 MB but when we applied the same changes to live, it increased to `16MB`.

Checking instede the `gitlab-chart-postgresql-0` and going to `gitlab-chart-postgresql-0:/bitnami/postgresql/conf/conf.`:

We can find the `override.conf` file that has:

```
cat override.conf
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 512MB
```

In theory, we should have 512 MB as we saw in the test environment instead of `16MB` we see allocated now.

I am pretty lost on why it's not working. One theory is that when I did the `helm upgrade gitlab-chart gitlab/gitlab --version x.x.x -f ./prod.yaml -n gitlab` not all the deployments and pods restarted, the postgresql pod did and we saw the change from `4MB` to `16MB` so there was something but not the intended value.

Any leads?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right thing?  Maybe you are inspecting work_mem and thinking it is shared_buffers?

Comment: Yes, this is what I get from the pod:

gitlabhq_production=> SHOW shared_buffers;
 shared_buffers
----------------
 16MB
(1 row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did an ALTER to the database and resetted the `postgresql` pod and the changes went through.

It seems if it does not restart all the necessary deployments, replicasets the changes do not get through all the time.